# Error in Intelij h2 config The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2, spring boot app

Tags: intellij-idea, h2

While trying to connect `H2` data source by URL in Intelij, following error occurs:

```
The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Switching to the right version fixed my problem.

To fixed it in Intelij, version of `H2` driver should be changed as following config:
In the Intelij, click on Data source config then in Drivers tab select H2 database.
[image]

Comment: switching to the right version, resolved my issue. many thanks

Comment: So how can I get that page..?

Answer (score 4):

H2 2.*.* cannot open database files created by H2 1.4.200 or older versions, you need to export them to SQL with the version that was used to create these files into SQL script (for example, with `SCRIPT TO 'filename.sql'` command), create a new database with the new version of H2 and populate it with data from this script (for example, with `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'filename.sql' FROM_1X` command).

See also the documentation:
https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#upgrade_backup_restore

H2 2.*.* has a helper class `org.h2.tools.Upgrade`, it can be used by applications to upgrade their databases.

There is also a third-party upgrade tool:
https://github.com/manticore-projects/H2MigrationTool

Answer (score 1):

Unless your h2 version is not specified in your pom.xml, select in @Tohid Makari print the version used in your pom.xml. Otherwise you can select "Latest version"

Answer (score 1):

Just try to test the connection and then you will get the below error and error itself says what version it needed and what version is provided.
So  just set the H2 driver version which is expected.

DBMS: H2 (ver. 1.4.200 (2019-10-14))  Case sensitivity: plain=upper, delimited=exact Driver: H2 JDBC Driver (ver. 1.4.200 (2019-10-14), JDBC4.1)
[HY000][50000] General error: "The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5]" [50000-210] The write format 1 is smaller than the supported format 2 [2.1.210/5].

In My case current set version was 2.1.210 but expected version is 1.4.200.

After updating version in IntelliJ now connection test is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause for this error might be a false url.
This happened to me when I copied my config from ProjectA to ProjectB and failed to change the url.

**Was**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./projectA/data
```

**Should have been**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./projectB/data
```

Answer (score 0):

This could happen too if you update Spring Boot and your previous database is in version1 (h2 runtime database for test purposes by example). If this is your case you can search your database file (C:\Users\user\databasename.mv.db) and delete it to regenerate (Or update it)

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientConnectionException: Versión del archivo de base de datos no soportada ó encabezado de archivo invalido en archivo "C:/Users/user/test.mv.db"
Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file "C:/Users/user/test.mv.db" [90048-214]
```